# Python's read and write add \x00 to the file

Tags: python, file-io

I have come across a weird problem when working with files in python. Let's say I have a text file and a simple piece of code that reads the contents of the file and then rewrites it with unaltered contents.

**File.txt**

> This is a test file

**Python code**

```
f=open(File.txt,'r+')
data=f.read()
f.truncate(0)
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

After running the above code `File.txt` seems to be the same. However, when I opened it in a hex editor I was surprised to see lots of `\x00` (NULL) bytes before the actual contents of the text file, that *wasn't* there before.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose your file has 20 bytes in it. So `f.read()` reads 20 bytes. Now you truncate the file to 0 bytes. But your position-in-file pointer is still at 20. Why wouldn't it be? You haven't moved it.  So when you write, you begin writing at the 21st byte. Your OS fills in the 20 missing bytes with zeroes.

To avoid this, `f.seek(0)` before writing again.

Answer (score 1):

`f.truncate(0)` sets all bytes of the file to `\x00`. However, it does not change the *file pointer* - you're still at the position after the call to `read`. Therefore, if you write anything, the operating system will extend the file to the new length (the original length + `len(data)`).

To avoid that, call [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek):

```
with open('File.txt', 'r+') as f:
  data=f.read()
  f.seek(0)
  f.truncate(0)
  f.write(data)
```

Comment: No, no, no. `.truncate` truncates the file. That's it; no null bytes. If the code ends with `f.truncate(0)`, the file becomes zero-sized. It's the `.write` on a file offset different than zero that causes the OS to fill the *unwritten* bytes with null bytes (or just *assume* that the unwritten bytes are null; it depends on the file system).