# Python/CMD - Getting an oddly specific error when using a very specific text file as input

Tags: python, cmd, txt

I am in a CS class and I am working on an assignment.
I have everything done but I am stuck on one huge error which makes no sense to me.

The command to run the first part of the program in CMD is such:

**python3 bead_tracker.py 25 180.0 25.0 data/run_1/***

(the * is used to omit a series of file names because I dont feel like typing that out)

This command outputs a bunch of floats up to 4 decimal places.
Things still work fine up to this point.

**python3 bead_tracker.py 25 180.0 25.0 data/run_1/* > output.txt**

Is used to store the outputs from the command into output.txt.
Opening up the file everything looks perfectly fine. Its just a series of numbers.

Our class uses https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stdio.py.html as a library for input and output. And the function `stdio.readString()` simply reads the first string from the standard input.

In this case, the function should return the first string from output.txt, which should be "11.1876".

Instead, it returns this monstrosity: ['ÿþ1\x001\x00.\x001\x008\x007\x006\x00'].

I thought it would be an issue with the function, stdio.readString(), but if I manually create a text file and put the same number in, it works perfectly.

I dont understand why this is happening.

Comment: It is Unicode text that you are getting…

Answer (score 1):

The array you call a `monstrosity` is actually the number you are seeking for, that is `11.1876` - but there are ASCII of `NULL` which is `\x00` at the beginning of each digit and the floating point. It's possibly related to the actual position of the pointer in the file and where your code thinks it is.

Without the code I cannot help so much but you could check this:
[Python's read and write add \x00 to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729452/pythons-read-and-write-add-x00-to-the-file)

Answer (score 0):

**Unicode Headers**

```
UTF-8 239 187 191 ï»¿ 
UTF-16 (BE) FE FF 254 255 þÿ 
UTF-16 (LE) FF FE 255 254 ÿþ 
UTF-32 (BE) 00 00 FE FF 0 0 254 255 ␀␀þÿ (␀ refers to the ASCII null character) 
UTF-32 (LE) FF FE 00 00[t 2] 255 254 0 0 ÿþ␀␀ (␀ refers to the ASCII null character) 
UTF-7[t 1] 2B 2F 76 38
```

As you can see from the table the file is UTF-16 LE. So either read in Unicode or write out ANSI. CMD.exe writes ANSI but if a program write to the screen in Unicode it will redirect the Unicode.